# Group by every year, year+9 and get total sum of count

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

How to group by specific range for every distinct years(by default years are distinct)?

**Input:**

```
my_table:

year  count
1961  2
1963  6
1969  3
1975  5
1976  9
1978  5
1983  3
1984  1
1985  3
1986  5
1987  6
1989  13
.
.
.
```

I have tried,

```
select sum(count) as total_count, 
       (year || '-' || year+9) as year_range 
from my_table 
group by year
```

But, the code is not giving correct results.

---

**Expected output:**

```
total_count  year_range
11           1961-1970
 9           1963-1972
22           1969-1978
23           1975-1984
23           1978-1987
.
.
.
```

Comment: How is 9 calculated for 1961-1970?  That looks like 11 to me.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I used `1961+9 = 1970`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a self join and aggregation:

```
select sum(m2.count) total_count,  
       m1.year || '-' || (m1.year + 9) year_range
from my_table m1 left join my_table m2
on m2.year between m1.year and m1.year + 9
group by m1.year
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=eeb3c21751b3b9db64a40427db65f3d1).
Results:

```
> total_count | year_range
> ----------: | :---------
>          11 | 1961-1970 
>           9 | 1963-1972 
>          22 | 1969-1978 
>          23 | 1975-1984 
>          21 | 1976-1985 
>          23 | 1978-1987 
>          31 | 1983-1992 
>          28 | 1984-1993 
>          27 | 1985-1994 
>          24 | 1986-1995 
>          19 | 1987-1996 
>          13 | 1989-1998
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions;

```
select t.*,
       sum(count) over (order by year range between current row and 9 following) as total_count
from t;
```

I don't know if you need `year_range`, but that is simply: `year || '-' || year + 9`.

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tepMeQuHNV3F5yMzhWrBZq/0) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @Pythoncoder . . . This does require a more recent version of SQLite.  Without a bit of research, I'm not sure exactly which version introduced this functionality (`range` didn't work in the original version that supported window functions).

Comment: Is this code is for `sqlite`? I'm still getting syntax error `': near "(": syntax error`

Comment: I'm using `sqlite 3.22.0`

Comment: @Pythoncoder . . . This does not work in that version.  You might consider upgrading; that version is two years old already.